# Renaming folder using a txt file

Tags: bash, rename

I'm working in my terminal using bash trying to rename the folders:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

I'd like to rename them according to a.txt file:

```
a 2 
c 3 
d 5 
e 1 
b 4
```

The order in the .txt file is completely random. I'm hoping to find a way where I can rename the folder so they become:

```
1 > e 
2 > a 
3 > c 
4 > b 
5 > d
```

Is there any way to do this? Note that I'm using OSX.

Comment: Hang on, is your file one line or many? Also, are all the target directories in the same place? What else is there in that directory?

Comment: My file has two colums with each 194 lines. All target directories are in the same "parent directory" as sub-folders. There is nothing else in the "parent directory" than the sub-folders (that I want to rename) and a txt file with the 194 lines.

Comment: OK. Please [edit] your question to include this information. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. Also tell us whether your target directory names can contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simple case you show above, where each line has two "words", the target directory and the new name, and where neither can contain any whitespace, you can simply do:

```
while read -r from to; do mv "$from" "$to"; done < file
```

That will read each line in `file` assign the first string (until the first whitespace) to `$from` and the rest of the line to `$to` and then run `mv` on each of them.